# modify for example .html method of jQuery

Tags: jquery

I understand that .html() can either get or set html for an object dependent on whether a parameter is passed to it.

However there are times when I want to modify the content before putting it into the parent object.  how would I modify .html() method to accept a 2nd parameter?

the specific application I am interested in is where the data is coming back from an ajax post.  due to existing conditions on the ap we have, I may get back HTML that is <div id="mydiv">...</div>.  That's the same `div` that it's going into, so I may want to set a parameter to strip the div itself first.  Or, I may want to set a parameter to just replace a subsection of the div.

Again, because of design constraints on the server end, it may not always be possible to modify the output coming from the server.

Comment: There are some possible options with the already existing overloads, but I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly. Can you give an example on how you want to modify the content, and why you can't just do that before you use it in the `html` method?

Comment: There's no second parameter in [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method of jQuery. Perhaps, you're talking about html(function(one,two){}) ????

Comment: If you aren't sure how to do it, how did you decide that rewriting `html()` method is the best solution for your situation?

Comment: What parameter you want to add to it?

Comment: @BojanPetkovski, modifying my post to give an example, sorry for not doing this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do but this might help you out:

http://jsfiddle.net/xdyv9uf3/

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/pu864k4q/show/",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#content').html(mod(data));
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert("There was an error");
    },
    complete: function (xhr, status) {
        $('#content').fadeIn();
    }
});

// Do your modifications here
function mod(data){
    var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#mydiv').html();
    var mod = result + ". This is the added content";
    return mod;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had not thought of this. Where I am looking to customize the chained method (or perhaps write my own) is that in some cases, perhaps I may choose not to write or append the content at all based on environmental factors.  PS thanks also for showing a use of fadeIn( ) for the data!

Comment: Glad that I could help. BTW You can accept the answer :)